# Mono.Cecil Delete Custom Attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, obfuscation, mono.cecil

I like to remove the ObfuscationExclude attribute from my assembly:

[image]

My attempt:

[image]

But I am not sure how i can do this, can someone help me out?

```
  public static void CleanCustomAttributes(AssemblyDefinition asmdef)
    {
        foreach(ModuleDefinition  ModuleDef in asmdef.Modules )
      {
            foreach(TypeDefinition TypeDef in ModuleDef.Types )
            {
               foreach(CustomAttribute CustomAttrib in TypeDef.CustomAttributes )
               {
                  if (CustomAttrib.AttributeType = // ? )
                  {

                  }
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code as a text, not as an image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the full name of the attribute and remove it.

```
public static void CleanCustomAttributes(AssemblyDefinition asmdef)
{
    foreach (ModuleDefinition ModuleDef in asmdef.Modules)
    {
        foreach (TypeDefinition TypeDef in ModuleDef.Types)
        {
            foreach (CustomAttribute CustomAttrib in TypeDef.CustomAttributes)
            {
                if (CustomAttrib.AttributeType.FullName == "System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute")
                {
                    TypeDef.CustomAttributes.Remove(CustomAttrib);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```